# Turning logical expression around

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic

I have the following code:

```
bool s = true;

for (...; ...; ...) {
    // code that defines A, B, C, D 
    // and w, x, y, z

    if (!(A < w) && s == true) {
        s = false;
    }

    if (!(B < x) && s == true) {
        s = false;
    }

    if (!(C < y) && s == true) {
        s = false;
    }

    if (!(D < z) && s == true) {
        s = false;
    }
}
```

This code is working well. However, I want to, for several (unimportant) reasons, change the code so that I can initiate `s = false;` and set it to true inside the if-statement. It tried the following:

```
bool s = false;

for (...; ...; ...) {
    // code that defines A, B, C, D 
    // and w, x, y, z

    if (A >= w && s == false) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (B >= x && s == false) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (C >= y && s == false) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (D >= z && s == false) {
        s = true;
    }
}
```

However, this is not working properly as the code above is working. I know thought wrong somewhere in the logic, but I can't figure out where. Does anbyone see my probably obvious error?

EDIT: Added three more if-statemets. Missed them since they were commented away.

Comment: Be aware that the negation of `A && B` is _not_ `!A && !B`, but `!A || !B)`

Comment: @thriqon But then he might as well just set s to true, as it will always enter the if.

Comment: change the condition (A < x && s == false)

Comment: Please show more information, maybe your entire for loop or how the results differ and what you expect.

Comment: Yes, it's not at all clear what you are trying to do. Based on the description I would say the above code is correct, but you say it isn't working, so need to see precisely what is different from what you expected.

Comment: You need to look up de Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!(A < x)` is the same as `A >= x` so your function hasn't reversed the logic at all. You need to use `A < x`.

I probably wouldn't bother checking the current state of `s` in the loop. Either you're flipping it or your not. And unless there's some reason to continue through the loop, I'd probably `break` after flipping `s`.

Answer (score 2):

[De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) says, you should also change `&&` to `||` .

Comment: Then it will enter that if on first loop, always.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on  [Wikipedias page on De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Negation_of_a_conjunction). The correct code for my problem is:

```
bool s = false;

for (...; ...; ...) {
    // code that defines A, B, C, D 
    // and w, x, y, z

    if (!(A >= w || s == false)) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (!(B >= x || s == false)) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (!(C >= y || s == false)) {
        s = true;
    }

    if (!(D >= z || s == false)) {
        s = true;
    }
}
```

Thanks @EJP for the tip!

Comment: `s == false` is always true, so `!(A >= w || s == false)` is always false and `s = true;` never gets executed unless s is already true.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the loop body that sets `s` is logically equivalent to this:

```
if(A >= w || B >= x || C >= y || D >= z)
    s = false;
```

Which, abstracting the condition, is equivalent to this:

```
s &= some_function(A, B, C, D, w, x, y, z);
```

You want to change it to this:

```
s |= some_other_function(A, B, C, D, w, x, y, z);
```

In the first case, `s` is true after the loop if `some_function` returns false on every iteration of the loop. In the second true, `s` is true after the loop if `some_other_function` returns true on *any* iteration of the loop.

`some_other_function` can only ever return true if `some_function` would return true on any iteration. But `some_other_function` only has access to the values from the current iteration. Therefore a valid `some_other_function` cannot exist.

This is assuming `s` must have the same value after the loop in both cases. Otherwise, you could trivially swap `true` and `false` in all the places relating to `s`.